# Android StartActivity run but nothing happens

Tags: android

I am creating an app that is a ticket sales system.  On the checkout page (the PaymentScreen activity) a check is performed to ensure that the customer is signed into their account, and if they are not, they are redirected to log in before continuing to checkout.

When I check to see if a customer is signed in, the code correctly verifies that the customer is not signed in, and then executes that if function (I can tell from LogCat), but the activity is never launched and the code continues to execute.

Any help would be appreciated - I can't seem to figure this one out.

PaymentScreen.java:

```
public class PaymentScreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.paymentscreen);

    if(Singleton.getInstance().selected_city == null) {
        PaymentScreen.this.startActivity(new Intent().setClass(PaymentScreen.this, CityList.class));
    }
    if(Singleton.getInstance().selected_venue == null) {
        PaymentScreen.this.startActivity(new Intent().setClass(PaymentScreen.this, VenueList.class));
    }
    if(Singleton.getInstance().selected_event == null) {
        PaymentScreen.this.startActivity(new Intent().setClass(PaymentScreen.this, EventList.class));
    }
    if(Singleton.getInstance().customer == null) {
        PaymentScreen.this.startActivity(new Intent().setClass(PaymentScreen.this, LoginScreen.class).putExtra("sendToActivity", "PaymentScreen"));
        Log.d("LineBouncer", "in if statement and (customer == null) is true");
    }
    if(Singleton.getInstance().customer == null) {
        Log.d("LineBouncer", "customer is null");
    }
    new GetPrepurchaseId().execute();
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
06-19 02:10:22.972: D/LineBouncer(3102): in if statement and (customer == null) is true
06-19 02:10:22.972: D/LineBouncer(3102): customer is null
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity android:name=".CityList" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginScreen" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity> 
    <activity android:name=".CreateAccount" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity> 
    <activity android:name=".VenueList" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity> 
    <activity android:name=".EventList" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".EventDetails" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".PaymentScreen" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".OrderHistory" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".PassView" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

So clearly from the LogCat the program recognizes that the customer is null and runs over the StartActivity code, but then continues to run and never actually starts that activity.

Thanks!

Comment: you missing this thing <activity android:name=".CityList" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity> in your manifest file

Comment: sorry - that is actually in there I just didn't post it in the snippet above.  I've updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to start activity is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PaymentScreen.this, EventList.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for that - I have updated my code to use this method of starting an activity.  The problem still exists in the code, however, that the code following the startActivity method still continues to run when I want it to go immediately to this new Activity without continuing.

Comment: Simply place a `return` in the `if` block of concern and it won't fall to perform the other statements. Or simply use `if`, `else if` and `else` to make all the blocks exclusive to each other

Comment: Ahhh, thank you.

I had assumed the default behavior of the startActivity method would be to immediately start the activity and not continue execution.  Do you know why code continues to execute after the startActivity is called by default?  This seems counter intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `PaymentScreen.this.startActivity(new Intent().setClass(PaymentScreen.this, CityList.class));`

try:

```
PaymentScreen.this.startActivity(new Intent(PaymentScreen.this, CityList.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
startActivity(new Intent(PaymentScreen.this, LoginScreen.class).putExtra("sendToActivity", "PaymentScreen"));
```

insted of

```
PaymentScreen.this.startActivity(new Intent().setClass(PaymentScreen.this, LoginScreen.class).putExtra("sendToActivity", "PaymentScreen"));
```

you can do it like

```
Intent in;
if(Singleton.getInstance().selected_city == null) {
        in=new Intent(PaymentScreen.this, CityList.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
    if(Singleton.getInstance().selected_venue == null) {
        in=new Intent(PaymentScreen.this, VenueList.class);
        startActivity(in);

    }
    if(Singleton.getInstance().selected_event == null) {
        in=new Intent(PaymentScreen.this, EventList.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
    if(Singleton.getInstance().customer == null) {
        in=new Intent(PaymentScreen.this, LoginScreen.class);
        in.putExtra("sendToActivity", "PaymentScreen");
        startActivity(in);
        Log.d("LineBouncer", "in if statement and (customer == null) is true");
    }
    if(Singleton.getInstance().customer == null) {
        Log.d("LineBouncer", "customer is null");
    }
    new GetPrepurchaseId().execute();
```

if u havnt mentioned this

```
<activity android:name=".CityList" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

in your manifest then declare it.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you had defined it in minifest..

it's better to call

```html
 context.startActivity()
```

insde